# NSURLSession time out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a problem that I cannot figure out.  I am using NSURLSession to send a POST to a restful API.  The restful API does not provide a response so the only delegate call back is didCompleteWithError and that error is a timeout.  Is there any way for me to get a response with the https status code and not worry about a response back?

Comment: The HTTP Status code is sent by the server, so you need to get a response if you want the status code.

Comment: Okay I get that much.  If I have no control over the server, is there anyway to just make NSURLSession make the post and not expect a response?

Comment: What does the server actually respond ? Does it respond a header ? Or nothing at all ?